# How to run a script to leave domain with systemd right before shutdown?

Tags: systemd, rhel

Right before shutdown I would like to run a script that makes an instance leave our domain on shutdown.

I have this as the `.service` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Service to remove domain join
After=network-online.target sssd.service realmd.service dbus.service dbus.socket

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/tmp/autoDomainLeave.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=poweroff.target
```

My script basically gets the service account details from AWS secrets store and then run the command:

```
echo $Password | realm leave --verbose --user=$Username corpnetwork.net
```

I have added some debugging in my script and this is the error message I am getting:

```
realm: Couldn't connect to realm service:
 Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.realmd:
 GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.ShuttingDown:
 Refusing activation, D-Bus is shutting down.
```

I have read all the documentation but I'm still not able to get it to work; can anyone help?

Comment: I also tried several combinations of Before, After, Wanted, Required... no luck. Dbus is always in the "shutting down" state.

Comment: Also, maybe we need to have the `realmd` service enabled and depend on it.